# HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error : system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-2.0

I created an ASP.NET web application MVC Core 2.2 project. Then I ran it in IIS Express. But I received the following error:

> HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error An ASP.NET setting has been
>   detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
>
> Most likely causes: system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true.
>
> Things you can try: If the application supports it, disable client
>   impersonation. If you are certain that it is OK to ignore this error,
>   it can be disabled by setting
>   system.webServer/validation@validateIntegratedModeConfiguration to
>   false.

This is my lunchSetting.json code:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50764",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:50764",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication2": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you make clear in your question which of the suggested fixes you have already tried (when googling for `500.24 asp.net core`)?

Comment: @mjwills nothing. Only I created an Simple ASP.NET web application MVC Core 2.2 project.I did not edit the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is wrong with your setup. `"windowsAuthentication": true` shouldn't be there. It's set to `false` by default, unless you are trying to set and use Windows Authentication. Setting up Windows Authentication requires special steps, including having a `web.config` file with `forwardWindowsAuthToken="True"` and `.UseIISIntegration()` in program.cs file. If you are not trying to do that, just set `"windowsAuthentication": false`.

Comment: thanks a lot Mr @VahidN . I created an ASP.NET web application MVC Core (2.1)  project The problem was solved and Runs , So I Use MVC Core 2.1 and Change Core From 2.1 To 2.2 in project Properites in VS . I think Core 2.2 Not Complete Installed

Answer (score 9):

Clearly not the poster's problem, since he wrote he fixed it changing .NET Core version; but I'm posting what worked for me, just in case.

Open IIS and find your default website:

[image: Default website]

Then you have two alternatives; the first is the quickest.

**1. Authentication**

Click on the Authentication icon:

[image: Authentication icon]

Right-click ASP.NET Impersonation and disable it.

[image: Disable impersonation]

**2. Configuration editor**

Open the configuration editor:

[image: Configuration editor]

The configuration editor opens; click the drop-down to the top left and pick system.web/identity:

[image: Drop-down]

Set impersonate to false:

[image: Impersonate]

And you're good to go!

Comment: I wonder why you need to use Configuration Editor, when Authentication offers a much simpler option to enable/disable ASP.NET Impersonation.

Comment: @LexLi duly noted, I added the Authentication way, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I received the same error as OP. My solution was to add a Web.config file to my ASP.NET Core web app's root folder with this XML content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>  
    <system.web>
      <identity impersonate="false"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: what to do if we do not want to add web.config manually?can we change in applicationhost.config? or can we resolve it using any other configuration which we can mention in lunchSetting.json

Comment: @KaranShah that may be possible. I only vaguely understand there's some kind of config file inheritance, so that's something I suggest you read up on as an alternative solution. Adding a Web.config file to the actual app works well for me as I can disable impersonation for this one particular application, which is all I wanted to accomplish! :)

Answer (score 0):

When create an .net core application in StartUp.cs you have to comment
//app.UseAuthorization();
then run your application it will work perfectly.