# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages project - An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

```
HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
```

Most likely cause:

> system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true.

I am trying to run a newly created asp.net core razor pages web application on my local machine and I when I try to run my application using IIS Express I get this internal server error.

If I change the profile to use WebApplication1 instead of IIS Express, then it works fine.

**UPDATE**

I added this to the applicatoinhost.config 
(C:\Users\psj\Desktop\test\WebApplication1.vs\WebApplication1\config) file and it seems to be working ok now with IIS express.

```
<system.web>
  <identity impersonate="false"/>
</system.web>
```

But i'm still not sure why I have to add this to the applicationhost.config  file in order to make it work.. Why isn't this done by default?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error : system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727477/http-error-500-24-internal-server-error-system-web-identityimpersonate-is-s)

Comment: no.. actually it looks like its some kind of problem with the iis express set up.  I simply started iis express and when I navigate to localhost:8080 I get this 500.24 error.  So I don't think its anything related to asp.net core.. but its looking more like some kind of IIS express set up error.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this problem.

The problem was in my root web.config file [C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config] it had:

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

Once I commented that out .. it worked fine.

Just posting this here in case anybody else runs in to this problem...