# Blazor template HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error : system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true

Tags: iis-express, blazor

I'm running into the above error when I run the untouched Blazor project.

A lot like this post [HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error : system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727477/http-error-500-24-internal-server-error-system-web-identityimpersonate-is-s)

**Difference is there's no "web.config" file.** Updating the "web.config" file to having the following piece of code in Core and MVC worked.

```
<system.web>
   <identity impersonate="false"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: What is the question when you already found the solution?

Comment: In blazor there is no web.config file. I'll highlight it in the text above

Comment: That simply indicates you enabled ASP.NET Impersonation at machine level. Go to IIS Manager and disable ASP.NET Impersonation under Authentication at server level (which should be disabled by default). That should stop this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set system.web/identity/impersonate to false in IIS Manager. See Francesco B's response in following post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60340688/6928182

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a web.config file you can simply add one by

```
right click the project and click add =>  new item
and from there select web configuration file and name it web.config
```

add the following lines in the web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>


  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```